# Error when creating a dropdown - ASP.NET MVC 4 using EF Database first approach - Implementing Ninject for DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

Please see the code below. I am trying to create a drop down by using EF database first approach, and implementing Ninject for DI. I'm new to these concepts, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

**Below is my Error:**

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

**Below is my Controller**

```
public class CitiesController: Controller
{
    private readonly ICitiesRepository repository;
    public CitiesController(ICitiesRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Models.MyViewModel();
        model.Cities = this
            .repository
            .GetAll()
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Thanks for selecting city: " + model.SelectedCityId);
    }
}
```

**I've got the below three classes (CityDTO, MyViewModel, MyModel) under Models Folder.**

**CityDTO.cs**

```
  public class CityDTO
    {
        public string CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }

    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
public interface ICitiesRepository
{
    IEnumerable<City> GetAll();
}

public class CitiesRepositoryEF: ICitiesRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<City> GetAll()
        {
            using (var ctx = new LocationEntities())
            {
                return ctx.usp_GetAllCities().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

**GlobalAsax.cs**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

**App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<Models.ICitiesRepository>().To<Models.CitiesRepositoryEF>();
        }
```

**And Below is my View:**

```
@model TestApp.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedCityID, Model.Cities, "Select City")
<button type = "submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: I get the following error when I try to Compile Mymodel.cs "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' "

Comment: can you show the code for usp_GetAllCities()?

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature says that it wants to return IEnumerable, but you are returning List.  Just tweek your method like so:

```
    public List<City> GetAll()
    {
        using (var ctx = new LocationEntities())
        {
            return ctx.usp_GetAllCities().ToList();  
        }
    }
```

Then you don't have to call ToList() in your action anymore.

```
model.Cities = this
        .repository
        .GetAll()
        //.ToList()  <-- delete this
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the code as you've mentioned, but i still get the below error. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EF.usp_GetAllCities_Result>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.CityDTO> ". Should I have to make any changes in the model browser of the .edmx file that gets the stored procedure from the database ? - thanks

Comment: Btw, the name of my stored procedure is usp_GetAllCities(). I created a complex type in the model browser, and named it as usp_GetAllCities_Result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CitiesRepositoryEF: ICitiesRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<City> GetAll() // <-- Generic of type City
    {
        using (var ctx = new LocationEntities())
        {
            return ctx.usp_GetAllCities().ToList(); // <-- Generic of type (result of usp_GetAllCities)
        }
    }
}
```

I think somehow the result of usp_GetAllCities() is is not reeturning a generic list (IEnumerable or whatever) of the same type (City). You should look into what the usp returns and make sure it's the same as what your GetAll() method wants to return.

But I'm not sure how EF handles the stored procedures and what is defined in your edmx and all, but it has to do with that mismatch.